# Strange error on increasing memory limit

Tags: php, php-5.3, concrete5

I am using a shared hosting environment and the default memory limit for PHP is 32M. I am facing some problems with Concrete5 setup.

When I try to sign into the admin panel of Concrete5, it gives memory limit error `Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted`. So I increased the memory limit with `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M')` to **128M**. After this I get an error that says:

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without 
sending any data.
```

I tried lowering the memory limit to 96M, 64M and some other values, but same error (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) repeats.

What is this error, and why does it occur when I use `ini_set()`?

Comment: Most probably your shared hosting environment doesn't permit tinkering with the memory_limit setting. Do you have access to the error logs? Those might contain a more verbose description of the error.

Comment: Yes as suggested by kitsched open apache server error log file and provide us the error details.We might help you after going through errors.

Comment: Raising PHP's allowed memory usage may make your process hit the system configured memory ulimit. PHP used to take that in a bad way and just terminate, which - unless it's been fixed lately - sounds like your problem.

Comment: Hey @JoachimIsaksson, can I get any log of PHP getting terminated, somewhere in apache or in system logs? It looks like this is the error as I am using PHP 5.2.14

Comment: @kitsched, Apache logs does not reflect any entries for empty response error. there are memory limit errors though. (errors that occur before increasing memory limit). Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried contacting your hosting provider and asking them about memory limits?

Comment: @kitsched, Yup getting in touch with them, Thanks man :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Can you add little details in answers section, so that i can select it as a best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Joachim Isaksson there is a flaw in older version (5.2.14) PHP that causes it to terminate. I upgraded the PHP version, and also increased the default memory_limit set by ulimit os call to 128M. this has resolved the error. Thanks guys... :)